# Pyserial or esptool directories not found on m1 mac arduino

Tags: arduino, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I am using an m1 MacBook pro and trying to run an arduino code on an ESP8266. Each time it gives me this error

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X (BigSur)), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

Executable segment sizes:
IROM   : 246940          - code in flash         (default or ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR) 
IRAM   : 27260   / 32768 - code in IRAM          (ICACHE_RAM_ATTR, ISRs...) 
DATA   : 1268  )         - initialized variables (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
RODATA : 924   ) / 81920 - constants             (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
BSS    : 25096 )         - zeroed variables      (global, static) in RAM/HEAP 
Sketch uses 276392 bytes (26%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27288 bytes (33%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54632 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
pyserial or esptool directories not found next to this upload.py tool.
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I don't know what the issue is, I tried to update these two folders with new ones that I found on another question but it didn't work.
I hope there is a way to run it.
Otherwise I tried on a Windows10 VM but there it doesn't see a driver so I can't upload in there too.

Answer (score 6):

I found an answer to my question :)
It can also depend on the issue but overall, you need to follow these steps:

1. Download https://github.com/espressif/esptool/archive/v3.0.zip
2. Download https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/archive/v3.4.zip
3. Unzip them (if needed)
4. go to ~/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/
5. Erase esptool and pyserial folders and replace with what you installed
6. Rename those folders pyserial and esptool (erase the numbers and spaces)

7.Restart Arduino and you are good to go.
The thing here is to be sure that you erased the version numbers and leave just "esptool" and "pyserial" names, if you don't Arduino will not recognise it and will still give errors.

Comment: Worked for me on an Intel MacBook Pro.